# Dynamic GP eConnect - Creating a new PMClassMaster

Tags: c#, econnect, dynamics-gp

I am finding my self looking in front of a wall right now. I've started working with eConnect to communicate with Dynamic GP in order to access information.

I've come accross a questions that I have yet to see answered and I'm tired of searching all over the web and all over the bunch of documents I have. In case someone reads this I'll give you a few sources after my question so you can guide your self even if this post doesn't help you.

My question is how can I create a new PMClassMaster through C#? In the end its an XML file that you need to generate but I wonder if there is a method that does that for me? For example, to create a new Vendor you can do the following:

```
PMVendorMasterType vendorMasterType = new PMVendorMasterType();

vendorMasterType.eConnectProcessInfo = new eConnectProcessInfo();
vendorMasterType.eConnectProcessInfo.ConnectionString = dynamicGPcs;


vendorMasterType.taUpdateCreateVendorRcd = new taUpdateCreateVendorRcd();

vendorMasterType.taUpdateCreateVendorRcd.VENDORID = vendorGP.VENDORID;
vendorMasterType.taUpdateCreateVendorRcd.VENDNAME = vendorGP.VENDNAME;
vendorMasterType.taUpdateCreateVendorRcd.VENDSHNM = vendorGP.VENDSHNM;

//... etc...

PMVendorMasterType[] vendors = { vendorMasterType };

eConnect.PMVendorMasterType = vendors;
```

This will pretty much create an XML for you, because thats what GP recevies through eConnect's "CreateEntity" and "UpdateEntity" methods.

I can't seem to find the same for PMClassMaster which is the table that has all the Vendor Class IDs. Does anyone know the answer? For reference: https://www.gptablereference.com/2010/Table/PM00100

----- Sources for GP -----

http://mbsguru.blogspot.pt/

http://victoriayudin.com/

http://www.gptablereference.com

Answer (score 0):

There is no eConnect node for the PM Class Master. Not everything that can be done in GP can be done via eConnect.

For this you will have to manually insert records into the relevant SQL table in the desired database.